# Socket programming with TCP/IP: recv() blocks

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp, ip

I am developing a simple Client/Server project which moves a chunk of data from client to server. I use TCP/IP.

The server sets up a listening socket and the client connects. First a short 16 byte "header" is transmitted containing some information including the amount of data to be transmitted after. Afterwards the big chunk is transmitted (around 2MB), namely

```
send( socketDesc, (void *) myBuffer, bigChunkSize, 0 );
```

and

```
recv( socketDescPeer, (void *) myBuffer, bigChunkSize, 0 )
```

First i implemented the client side under windows using winsock2, which works without problems. I now tried to port this implementation to linux, in which case the server side never returns from the recv() call (the "header" however is transmitted correctly). I then tried to send the data in smaller chunks of fixed size like this

```
unsigned int byteSent = 0;
while( byteSent < bigChunkSize ) {
    int result = send( socketDesc, (void *) myBuffer, smallChunkSize, 0 );
    if ( result < 0 ) {...} else { byteSent += result; }
}
```

Now, the server receives the first few number of chunks but then again, blocks.

Any ideas? Keep in mind that transmission works  without problems using winsock2! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are your sure the header is transmitted correctly, and with this the chunk's size? Is it send in binary format?

Comment: The header is transmitted as 4 ints. I also tried to hardcode the chunk size.

Comment: Did you run the code in a debugger, and **explicitly** observed the call to `recv()`/`read()` **not** returning?

Comment: However `read()`/`recv()` only blocks (on an blocking socket) if **nothing** is around to be read/received and the sender did not shut down the connection.

Comment: You need to check for a zero return as well, and break if you get it. At present you will just spin at end of stream.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the return code of send to check, how many bytes were really send? Neither send nor recv are guaranteed to send/receive the given number of bytes. They can handle less and you have to call send/recv again to handle the rest.

So if you actually send less bytes than expected it explains, why the recv will block waiting for more data (which were not send).

Comment: It wouldn't block if all data should be received with one call. It would return then having read as much bytes as there were sent. And if the OP's code does loop around the `send()`, I do not expect his/her code to loop around the `recv()`.

Comment: Yes i checked the return values. For both the and small chunk size the amount if bytes sent is as expected. In the case of small chunks, the first few received chunks before the block also have the correct size.

Comment: @madmax1: it's really hard to get from the description, what you are really doing. Please do a small complete example of your problem so that one can analyze it. Given your description of what you do the example would probably small enough to post here. I just guess that the problem lies in code you did not show here.

Comment: @alk You are incorrect. `recv()` isn't obliged to transfer more than one byte, in blocking mode. It makes no attempt to fill the buffer. You have to loop.

Comment: @EJP I fully agree and I did not want to express that `recv()` would block. However it seems I expressed my self unclear, as you might draw from my 2nd comment to the OP.